# How to create separate log files for every jar that present in war file in JBOSS EAP/Wildfly

Tags: jboss, log4j, wildfly-11

I have deployed one war file in JBOSS eap7.4, but all my logs are going to server.log file by default. I have 2 jars in my war file for which I need to log messages in separate files. Please help me.

This is the custom handler I have created in standalone.xml

And this is the module.xml

[This is my log4j.xml file to implement logs for 2 jars with their package names](https://i.stack.imgur.com/svATb.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

You need to exclude the `org.apache.logging.api` from your deployment in a `jboss-deployment-structure.xml` file. Then include both the log4j-api and log4j-core libraries in your deployment if you want to use a log4j2 configuration file. See the JBoss EAP 7.4 [documentation](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_jboss_enterprise_application_platform/7.4/html/development_guide/logging_for_developers#creating-log4j2-logmanager-implementation_default) for more details.

Comment: Try  <logging-profiles>   <logging-profile name="accounts-app-profile">
      <file-handler name="ejb-trace-file">
         <level name="DEBUG"/>
         <file relative-to="jboss.server.log.dir" path="ejb-trace.log"/>
      </file-handler>
      <logger category="com.company.accounts.ejbs">
         <level name="TRACE"/>
         <handlers>
            <handler name="ejb-trace-file"/>
         </handlers>
      </logger>
   </logging-profile>
</logging-profiles> After that In your war ,add this line in manifest file   Manifest-Version: 1.0
Logging-Profile: accounts-app-profile

Answer (score 0):

You need to achieve this using logging profiles. Please refer
https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_jboss_enterprise_application_platform/6.4/html/administration_and_configuration_guide/sect-logging_profiles

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).